# Why $\sqrt p \in\mathbb Q(\xi_p)$?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, quadratic-residues, quadratic-reciprocity

> If $p\equiv 1 \, \mathrm {mod} \, 4$ is a prime, then $\sqrt p \in\mathbb Q(\xi_p)$ where $\xi_p$ is the $p$-th root of unity.

How to prove the above claim?

(I need this fact to prove quadratic reciprocity law in J.S. Miline's Algebraic Number Theory on p 143, it metions $p$ is the only prime ramifying in $\mathbb Q [\sqrt p]$, I'm not sure wether it helps or not.)

Comment: Thus must be a duplicate. The standard arguments are a) quadratic Gauss sums and b) ramification: In the cyclotomic field, only $p$ ramifies; thus the quadratic subfield (Gaois theory) is nly ramified at $p$, and there is only one such quadratic extension.